# How to load part of image in bevy engine

Tags: rust, sprite, game-engine, bevy

I have a sprite sheet png file that contains some static sprites like walls or grass. How can I split them into individual sprites by their coordinate in the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not post any code or what you tried so far, so I am providing a general answer.

There are multiple options:

- You can use `texture2DArray` in your shader, like shown [here](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/examples/shader/array_texture.rs) or [here](https://github.com/bonsairobo/building-blocks/blob/main/examples/array_texture_materials/array_texture_materials.rs).
- You can modify the UV - coordinates of your mesh to accomplish this

I personally like the uv coordinate manipulation more, a basic sample would look like this with `bevy = 0.4`:

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::build()
        .add_resource(Msaa { samples: 4 })
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup.system())
        .run();
}

/// set up a simple 3D scene
fn setup(
    commands: &mut Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
) {

    let texture_handle = asset_server.load("textures/sprites_array.png");

    let material_handle = materials.add(StandardMaterial {
        albedo_texture: Some(texture_handle.clone()),
        shaded: false,
        ..Default::default()
    });

    let mut uvs = Vec::new();
    uvs.push([0.0, 1.0]);
    uvs.push([0.0, 0.0]);
    uvs.push([1.0, 0.0]);
    uvs.push([1.0, 1.0]);

    let mut mesh = Mesh::from(shape::Quad::new(Vec2::new(1.0, 1.0)));
    mesh.set_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, uvs);

    // use only the upper left part of the texture atlas
    let mut uvs1 = Vec::new();
    uvs1.push([0.0, 0.5]);
    uvs1.push([0.0, 0.0]);
    uvs1.push([0.5, 0.0]);
    uvs1.push([0.5, 0.5]);

    let mut mesh1 = Mesh::from(shape::Quad::new(Vec2::new(1.0, 1.0)));
    mesh1.set_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, uvs1);

    // use only the lower right part of the texture atlas
    let mut uvs2 = Vec::new();
    uvs2.push([0.5, 1.0]);
    uvs2.push([0.5, 0.5]);
    uvs2.push([1.0, 0.5]);
    uvs2.push([1.0, 1.0]);

    let mut mesh2 = Mesh::from(shape::Quad::new(Vec2::new(1.0, 1.0)));
    mesh2.set_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, uvs2);

    // add entities to the world
    commands
        // the whole texture array
        .spawn(PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshes.add(mesh),
            material: material_handle.clone(),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        // only the "first" item of the texture array
        .spawn(PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshes.add(mesh1),
            material: material_handle.clone(),
            transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(2.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        // only the "last" item of the texture array
        .spawn(PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshes.add(mesh2),
            material: material_handle.clone(),
            transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        // light
        .spawn(LightBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(4.0, 8.0, 4.0)),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        // camera
        .spawn(Camera3dBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 5.0))
                .looking_at(Vec3::default(), Vec3::unit_y()),
            ..Default::default()
        });
}
```

I used this texture array (put it in `assets/textures/sprites_array.png`):
[image: Texture]

Which will then result in that scene:
[image: The bevy scene.]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's exactly what I want!